# How can django redefine DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE when I run tests?

Tags: python, django

I have a "settings" directory in the root of my project. It contains different files with settings:

```
./settings/tests.py
./settings/testing.py
./settings/production.py
```

I want to use tests.py for unit tests (I use testing.py for preproduction application run), so. In **manage.py** file I wrote these code:

```
...
if 'test' in sys.argv:
  os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'settings.tests')
else:
  os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE',
                        'settings.production')
...
```

When I run `python manage.py test <app_name>`, all the tests run perfectly and the settings/tests.py module is used. But when I run `python manage.py test`, Django loads settigns/testing.py file.

When I rename testing.py file, everything works as I expect: tests.py module is loaded.

Is there any logic about locating testing module for tests in Django? How can I disable it?

Comment: Came here trying to configure settings for test environment. I like your trick with `if 'test' in sys.argv:`, because I don't want to use `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` variable. But for consistency decided to use it in the `settings/dev.py` (not in `manage.py`) and check `if 'test' is NOT in the sys.argv, then it's a Dev mode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the module was loaded by "test*" pattern match.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `--settings` flag to provide settings when running your tests:

```
python manage.py test --settings=your_app_name.settings.tests
```

This is one of the ways to do it.

Comment: It didn't help:
I ran `python manage.py test --settings=settings.tests`, but it still loads the settings/testing.py module

Comment: Did you replace `your_app` with your own app name?

Comment: My `settings` directory is on the same level with all my django apps.
I want to run tests for all the apps.

Comment: what is the name of the directory within which the settings directory is?

Comment: it is the project directory `my_project`. I tried to use in your command, but I get
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_project.settings'`

In all other cases the settings module selection works just fine. The only think that spoils it - the existing of testing.py setting module - with the exact name.

Comment: Then it should be `my_project.settings.tests`